# vue.js / vue-router - create instance of single file component with props to route to

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My goal is to further reduce code and the most obvious one in my project is to abstract lists. Currently I have a vue single file component called `List` which includes an async data loader. I've also created a bunch of 'derived' single file components using this `List` component as root tag element, passing props as needed to load the correct data.

Now, since I've split up my components into separate files using [this](https://github.com/pksunkara/vue-builder-webpack-plugin) plugin it is common to have a folder structure which looks like this:

```
\components\
\components\List\
\components\List\List.vue
\components\List\List.vue.js
\components\List\List.scoped.vue.css
\components\List\List.vue.html
```

As you can see, 4 files per component. Imagine having 10 different list components all using `List` as their base. That is 10 folders with a total of 40 files. And for what? Pretty much the same code, 2-3 values that change (the properties), the rest stays the same.

I've been trying to adjust `List` so that I can create an instance of it and pass the properties as constructor values. Why? Instead of having 1 folder with 4 files per list, I could just have the base `List` and the create the components like so:

```
let FooList = new List('foo', true, {}, (x) => {});
let BarList = new List('bar', false, {}, (y) => {});
```

I want to use these objects in the vue-router like so:

```
const router = new Router({
  ...
  routes: [
    {
      path: "some/foo,
      component: FooList,
    },{
      path: "any/bar,
      component: BarList,
    },
  ]
});
```

Anything I tried failed.
What have I tried so far?

`export default { ... }` exports a default single file component. I figured if this is a component, I might as well just override some values in it.

How did I try to do this?

I tried using `Object.assign({ ... }, List)` in the hope of creating a `List` object which has the properties defined like I want them to be.
I also tried using the vue built in "extends" option of single files components to extend `List`, but this doesn't save code at all since I still need to define a template/render method for the component .. which results in those 4 files again. I tried to use `Vue.component(..)` and `Vue.extend(..)`, alone and in combination but couldn't succeed.

Anything I tried resulted either in a max stack exceeded exception (recursion gone wrong), vue errors were thrown stating that something doesn't fit or just not displaying anything at all.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `prop` on the `List` component to specify the type of list and modify the behavior.

```
let routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: List,
    props: { config: { type: 'Listing', display: 'Tile' } }
  },
]
```

Comment: oh you can define the props directly in the router? that is awsome! I'm going to try this asap and get back to you